# RedirectAttribute not work - model is empty in Spring mvc controller

Tags: spring-mvc

I use flashAttribute for redirect data to other controller action.
 But model is empty. The code seems right. Same code in other action work like a charm. The only difference is a @PathVariable on method signature

```
@RequestMapping("/user/edit-execute")
public String editExecute(@ModelAttribute @Valid UserEditForm userEditForm, BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes attr,HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
    basePath =""
    ModelAndView m = new ModelAndView("user.edit");
    ModelAndView redirect = new ModelAndView("redirect:/user/");

    HttpSession session = httpServletRequest.getSession();

    try{
        if(userEditForm.getStatus()==null){
            userEditForm.setStatus(0);
        }

        if(!result.hasFieldErrors()) {
            userDaoCrud.update(userEditForm, userEditForm.getId_user());
            session.setAttribute("message", "Operazione completata con successo.");
            session.setAttribute("css_class", "dashboard_ok");
            return "redirect: " + basePath + "/user";
        }else{
            attr.addFlashAttribute("org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.userEditForm", result);
            attr.addFlashAttribute("userEditForm", userEditForm);
            return "redirect: " + basePath + "/user/edit/"+userEditForm.getId_user();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "redirect: " + basePath + "/user/edit/"+userEditForm.getId_user();
    }
}



 @RequestMapping("/user/edit/{id}")
public String edit(Model model, @PathVariable("id") int id, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {


    logger.warn(model);
    ....
    return "user.edit";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's necessary return a ModelAndView object. Simple string not work.